# subprocess Popen opens bash script and runs. Want to open another bash

Tags: python

Python script has subprocess to Popen bash script. This works. Now I want to repeat and open another bash script. Do I need to close 1st subprocess first?

Comment: Is the script still running?

Comment: The Python script starts and when it reaches subprocess.Popen, a short bash script opens, completes and returns. I have no close statement. Now, I want to run another similar bash script. It did not work and main python script froze. I use this.....  `subprocess.Popen(["bash", "file.sh"])`